# Convert jQuery plugin to conditional inline jQuery?

Tags: jquery, mobile, plugins, inline, swipe

I've been working to implement the '[Simple Swiper](http://www.jqueryscript.net/mobile/jQuery-Plugin-To-Load-New-Pages-When-You-Swipe-Simple-Swiper.html)' plugin, but as the jQuery mobile .js and .css are comparatively large, I was using a conditional to load these only for mobile devices.

However, the Simple Swiper plugin does not properly load using jQuery's `getScript()` method--or via ajax directly--though the jQuery.mobile.js script loads fine. I tried various other workarounds to get the plugin .js to load but failed.

I don't know if this is asking too much, but is there any convention for converting an external plugin to run inline within existing jQuery script--to circumvent the problem of loading it conditionally? (Forgive me if this is an incredibly n00b question.)

The plugin itself is not very long, but the jQuery structure is a little over my head. You can see their full code at the link above, but otherwise here's how their plugin starts and ends:

```
//STARTS
(function ($, window, undefined) {
    $.widget("mobile.swiper", $.mobile.widget, {
        options:{
            swipeleft:null,
            swiperight:null
        },
        _init: function () {
        //etc...

//ENDS
//etc...
});

    $(document).on("pageinit", function (event) {
        var page = $(event.target);
        var swleft = page.data('swipeleft');
        var swright = page.data('swiperight');
        if (swleft !== undefined || swright !== undefined) {
            //apply our widget if swipeleft or swiperight is defined.
            page.swiper();
        }
    });
})(jQuery, this);
```

I'd appreciate any insights. (FWIW: Other attempts at implementing swipe-to-navigate setups--without this plugin--failed due to some really bizarre behavior, particularly when swiping right. This plugin seemed to fix all that.)